# Combining multiple rows to get a single one

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

Source table :

```
----------------------------------------
| Employee Name   | department | Emp Id |
----------------------------------------
| Sam             | Sales      | 101    |
----------------------------------------
| Sam             | Finance    | 101    |
----------------------------------------
| Dirk            | marketing  | 102    |
----------------------------------------
| Dirk            | Research   | 102    |
----------------------------------------
```

Output needed :

```
------------------------------------------------------
| Employee Name   | Emp Id | department1 | department2|
------------------------------------------------------
| Sam             | 101    | Sales       | Finance    |
------------------------------------------------------
| Dirk            | 102    | marketing   | Research   |
------------------------------------------------------
```

Can you kindly help with what functions or query should I use to get above mentioned output?

Answer (score 1):

There are two known techniques to pivot the data

1. Through use of **Conditional Aggregation**

```sql
SELECT EmployeeName, EmpId,
       MAX(DECODE(rn,1,Department)) AS Department_1,
       MAX(DECODE(rn,2,Department)) AS Department_2
  FROM (
        SELECT t.*, 
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
               (PARTITION BY EmpId,EmployeeName ORDER BY Department) AS rn
          FROM t
       )
GROUP BY EmployeeName, EmpId
```

2.By using **PIVOT** Clause

```sql
SELECT *
  FROM (
        SELECT t.*, 
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
               (PARTITION BY EmpId,EmployeeName ORDER BY Department) AS rn
          FROM t
       )
 PIVOT
 (
  MAX(Department) AS Department FOR rn IN (1,2)
 )
```

for both cases need to enumerate the pivoted department columns. For this, `ROW_NUMBER()` analytic function suits well

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=d922eb6beff3b7cdd7b4e2538e8a9efe)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

If you only have two values, you can use `max()` and `min()`:

```
select name, empid,
       min(department) as department1,
       nullif(max(department), min(department)) as department2
from t
group by name, empid;
```